# OpenLayers5 with mapbox layer zoom issue

Tags: openlayers, vector-tiles

I'm having an issue with a MapBox vector layer in OpenLayers (latest version). It works with mapboxjs, but I cannot make it work propperly in OL5.

The problem is that the layer shows all elements at zoom 14, really far, and there are a lot of dot elements so it slows the browser. In mapbox it doesn't do that and loads all elements properly.

```
new VectorTileSource({
            format: new MVT(),
            url: 'https://maps.blackcore.mx/planet/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf?access_token=' + token
        })
```

Has anybody make it work? Are styles capable of making elements render or not or is it a tile problem?

I have tried with the official example's code:
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/mapbox-vector-tiles.html

Also tried this plugin to test styles:
https://github.com/boundlessgeo/ol-mapbox-style

Comment: Take a look at the style function used in the example  https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/resources/mapbox-streets-v6-style.js  If you search for resolution you can see that some features are only included if the resolution is below a certain value.  To avoid hard coding resolutions you can calculate the resolution for a zoom level using `source.getTileGrid.getResolution(zoom)` or `view.getResolutionForZoom(zoom)`.

Comment: Thank you! I will try something like that :)

Comment: There have been some performance improvements since v5.3.0. Does https://27-4974939-gh.circle-artifacts.com/0/examples/mapbox-style.html perform as expected for you? That example also uses ol-mapbox-style.

Comment: I will try that too, thank you.